# Can't stop the code execution in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, execution

I took an MIT/GPL-licenced jQueryPlugin (for zooming) and modified it to fit my needs.
Unfortunately, the code execution does not stop as intended. In theory, it shoud stop in the moment, when the mouse leaves the image that in marked for the zoom.

In the "cursorPOS" function, there is a check if the mouse is outside of the container:

```
if (posY < offset.top || posX < offset.left || posY > (offset.top + imageHeight) || posX > (offset.left + imageWidth)) {
    $(imagezoomCursor.selector).remove();
    $('#RadialBox > img[id!="TraversalZoomImage5x"]').remove();
    $('#RadialBox').removeClass('radialzoom-view').append('<img data-radialzoom="' + radialZoomSource + '" src="' + radialSource + '" class="radialzoom">');
    return;
}
```

It executes perfectly well, but it does not stop executing, even though I send the return command. Does anyone have an idea, how to fix this?

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        cursorColor: '237,241,244',
        cursorOpacity: 1,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        zoomviewsize: [0, 0],
        magnification: 3,

    };

    var imagezoomCursor, imagezoomView, settings, imageWidth, imageHeight, offset;
    var radialmethods = {
        init: function (options) {
            $this = $(this),
                imagezoomCursor = $('.radialzoom-cursor'),
                imagezoomView = $('.radialzoom-view'),

                $(document).on('mouseenter', $this.selector, function (e) {
                    var data = $(this).data();
                    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options, data);
                    offset = $(this).offset();
                    imageWidth = $(this).width();
                    imageHeight = $(this).height();
                    settings.zoomviewsize = [$(this).parent().width(), $(this).parent().height()];

                    cursorSize = [(settings.zoomviewsize[0] / settings.magnification), (settings.zoomviewsize[1] / settings.magnification)];

                    $original = $(this);

                    radialZoomSource = $(this).attr('data-radialzoom');
                    radialSource = $(this).attr('src');

                    var posX = e.pageX,
                        posY = e.pageY,
                        zoomViewPositionX;
                    $('body').prepend('<div class="radialzoom-cursor">&nbsp;</div>');
                    $('#RadialBox').addClass('radialzoom-view').prepend('<img id="RadialZoomImage" src="' + radialZoomSource + '">');

                    $(imagezoomView.selector).css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'z-index': 7,
                        'overflow': 'hidden',
                    });

                    $(imagezoomView.selector).children('img').css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'width': imageWidth * settings.magnification,
                        'height': imageHeight * settings.magnification,

                    });

                    $(imagezoomCursor.selector).css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'width': cursorSize[0],
                        'height': cursorSize[1],
                        'background-color': 'rgb(' + settings.cursorColor + ')',
                        'z-index': 7,
                        'opacity': settings.cursorOpacity,
                        'cursor': settings.cursor,
                        'border': settings.cursorBorder,
                    });

                    $(imagezoomCursor.selector).css({
                        'top': posY - (cursorSize[1] / 2),
                        'left': posX
                    });

                    $(document).on('mousemove', document.body, radialmethods.cursorPos);

                });
        },

        cursorPos: function (e) {
            var posX = e.pageX,
                posY = e.pageY;
            if (posY < offset.top || posX < offset.left || posY > (offset.top + imageHeight) || posX > (offset.left + imageWidth)) {
                $(imagezoomCursor.selector).remove();


                $('#RadialBox > img[id!="TraversalZoomImage5x"]').remove();

                $('#RadialBox').removeClass('radialzoom-view').append('<img data-radialzoom="' + radialZoomSource + '" src="' + radialSource + '" class="radialzoom">');

                return;
            }



            if (posX - (cursorSize[0] / 2) < offset.left) {
                posX = offset.left + (cursorSize[0] / 2);
            } else if (posX + (cursorSize[0] / 2) > offset.left + imageWidth) {
                posX = (offset.left + imageWidth) - (cursorSize[0] / 2);
            }

            if (posY - (cursorSize[1] / 2) < offset.top) {
                posY = offset.top + (cursorSize[1] / 2);
            } else if (posY + (cursorSize[1] / 2) > offset.top + imageHeight) {
                posY = (offset.top + imageHeight) - (cursorSize[1] / 2);
            }

            $(imagezoomCursor.selector).css({
                'top': posY - (cursorSize[1] / 2),
                'left': posX - (cursorSize[0] / 2)
            });
            $(imagezoomView.selector).children('img').css({
                'top': ((offset.top - posY) + (cursorSize[1] / 2)) * settings.magnification,
                'left': ((offset.left - posX) + (cursorSize[0] / 2)) * settings.magnification
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.radialZoom = function (method) {
        if (radialmethods[method]) {
            return radialmethods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return radialmethods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error(method);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-radialzoom]').radialZoom();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of your code..

Comment: unfortunatly not, there are too many necessary file to make it work

Comment: can you post the html of your code atleast..may be others could try creating a fiddle for you.. and how are you invoking this plugin in your javascript..